# ffmpeg combine 3 filter_complex commands

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Can anyone help me. I want to combine 3 ffmpeg commands:

1:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf scale=720:-2,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy out1.mp4
```

2:

```
ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]crop=$url_width_:$barik:$url_width_:$url_height_, boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v]crop=$url_width_:$barik:0:0,boxblur=10[fg2]; [0:v][fg]'overlay=0:$blur_y'[bg]; [bg][fg2]overlay=0:0' -preset ultrafast -c:a copy out2.mp4
```

3:

```
ffmpeg -i out2.mp4 -i $wmf -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw*$scale:-1[wm];[0][wm] overlay=$pos' -preset ultrafast -codec:a copy final.mp4
```

Please help me to combine this commands to one command.

Answer (score 1):

As follows:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i $wmf -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=720:-2,split=3[v0][fg][fg2];[fg]crop=$url_width_:$barik:$url_width_:$url_height_, boxblur=10[fg]; [fg2]crop=$url_width_:$barik:0:0,boxblur=10[fg2];[v0][fg]'overlay=0:$blur_y'[bg]; [bg][fg2]overlay=0:0[v0];[1]scale=iw*$scale:-1[wm];[v0][wm] overlay=$pos' -preset ultrafast -c:a copy final.mp4`